# How to right click a specific location using Sikuli?

Tags: location, jython, right-click, sikuli, multiple-monitors

I am using Sikuli to automatically run batch analysis of airfoils in XFLR5. I have pretty solid code that will open the files, run the analysis, and then start exporting the graphs by right clicking on them, HOWEVER, Sikuli is having a hard time finding XFLR GUI elements (or is otherwise acting weird).

I am using a multimonitor setup, but I restricted my region to the left most monitor (which should be Screen(0) since this is my laptops main screen). However, my windows start menu is on the middle monitor instead of the laptops.

Originally, I was unable to adjust the target offset of my screenshots, which motivated me to find a way to just perform region.rightClick((x,y)) on the next graph I need, but Sikuli keeps throwing errors.

So basically, how do you define a location to get 
    region.rightClick( (x+1150, y+200) )
to click some arbitrary point that I know the location of? I've tried as many ways as I can think of but to no avail.

My most recent, most frustrating error is "attribute error"(write only attr: location) when I call:

```
def saveGraph(int_graph, region, filename):
x = region.getX()
y = region.getY()
region.rightClick( (x+1150, y+200) )
```

(It throws the error on line 4)

Comment: It is not really clear what is your initial problem. Why do you have to use offset click rather than a regular approach? Do you have issues uniquely identifying your object (e.g. it has a variable shape)?

Comment: I'm trying to automate exporting graphs that are drawn on the screen. There's 5 graphs that get updated based on the airfoil shape. They'll always be in the same location on the screen, but I'm having a hard time getting sikuli to right click in the appropriate locations.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
region.rightClick(Location(x+1150, y+200)) or
region.rightClick(Location(x, y).offset(1150,200))
```